# Duplicated figure names in word output in papaja

Tags: r, r-markdown, docx, figure, papaja

After knitting a word document produced by the papaja package, figure names are duplicated [see there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91ae5.png). Does anyone know how to fix this, please?

papaja version is as follows: 0.1.0.999

Reproducible code is as follows:

````
---
title             : "The title"
shorttitle        : "Title"

author: 
  - name          : "First Author"
    affiliation   : "1"
    corresponding : yes    # Define only one corresponding author
    address       : "Postal address"
    email         : "my@email.com"
    role:         # Contributorship roles (e.g., CRediT, https://casrai.org/credit/)
      - Conceptualization
      - Writing - Original Draft Preparation
      - Writing - Review & Editing
  - name          : "Ernst-August Doelle"
    affiliation   : "1,2"
    role:
      - Writing - Review & Editing

keywords          : "keywords"
wordcount         : "X"

bibliography      : ["r-references.bib"]

floatsintext      : no
figurelist        : no
tablelist         : no
footnotelist      : no
linenumbers       : yes
mask              : no
draft             : no

documentclass     : "apa6"
classoption       : "man"
output            : papaja::apa6_docx
---
    
    ```{r setup, include = FALSE}
     library("papaja")
     r_refs("r-references.bib")
    ```

    (ref:my-figure1-caption) this is figure 1

    ```{r my-figure1, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="(ref:my-figure1-caption)"}
    plot(mtcars)
    ```

    (ref:my-figure2-caption) This is figure 2

    ```{r my-figure2, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="(ref:my-figure2-caption)"}
    plot(mtcars$mpg)
    ```
````

Comment: Hi Lukas, I cannot reproduce the duplicated figure captions. However, the current release version of the package is rather outdated, and it might be worthwhile to install the development version to see if the problem persists. For this purpose, you can use `remotes::install_github("crsh/papaja@devel")`